# Undoing a $request->merge()

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm creating a bit of code where I take the request and TEMPORARILY add some parameters to it via `$request->merge()`

At some later point in the code, I would like to be able to restore the request to what it was initially. However, the bit of code that is restoring it won't explicitly know what things were merged in. It will, however, be able to access a variable I set at the start of the function, `$rall = $request->all();` -- if it's possible to restore the initial state of the request with that variable, that'd be brilliant!

Comment: Are you using form requests and only need to merge the data for validation? If so I believe there's a `validationData()` method where you can manipulate the data for validation and leave the original request values untouched.

Comment: No, for my case i need to change the request so that other functions can do `$request->get()` and get the data the need

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION 1:

You may use the `createFrom` static method ([see documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_createFrom))

```
$requestCopy = Request::createFrom($request);

$requestCopy->merge([
   "foo" => "bar",
   // .....
]);

// $request remains intact
```

SOLUTION 2:

Use the PHP native `clone` [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php). Please note that the clone only does a shallow copy of the request object, but anyway I don't think you will have nested objects inside your request...

```
$requestCopy = clone $request;

$requestCopy->merge([
   "foo" => "bar",
   // .....
]);

// $request remains intact
```

SOLUTION 3:

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_duplicate), you may use the `duplicate` method to achieve your goal.

```
$requestDuplicate = $request->duplicate();

$requestDuplicate->merge([
   "foo" => "bar",
   // .....
]);

// $request will keep the same state
```

Comment: Oh, hmm, I actually think in this case that my best bet is to keep the original request alone, and to do the `->merge` on duplicated requests! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately something happened I didn't expect. Here's my test code: `$newRequest = $request->duplicate();
        $newRequest->merge(['hello' => 'world']);` Now, you would expect this to add the 'hello' key to the newRequest but not to the original one, but when i do `$request->all()`, the hello world parameter is in there! Why would that be?

Comment: Just to be clear, that happens both ways -- whether i do the `->merge` on the new request or the original one, the merged keys end up in both requests.

Comment: That's weird because it's working for me! can you please post the whole script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your intial request data in one variable and later on add addition data as below:

```
$reqDatatOld = $request->all();
```

Then do your `$request->merge()` and use it anywhere in code. when you required old data then use it the variable we created `$reqDatatOld`

Comment: nah, cause the whole point is that i would need `$reqDataOld` to behave the same as a `$reqest` object, to have the same methods so I can pass it to functions that expect an actual Request. Just an array storing the original requedst isn't good enough, I'd need a Request object with the initial request, while also being able to make Request objects with changes added by `->merge()`

Answer (score 0):

I was very hopeful for Yezan's answer to work, I was sure it was! But it didn't.

But I looked at the docs that he linked and found the `->replace` method, which I can actually use to do what I want.

Basically, I store the original `$originalRequestData = $request->all()` method at the beginning of the process, and I can `->merge()` data into the request as I need, and when I'm ready to return the request to its initial state, I do `$request->replace($originalRequestData);` and it works perfectly as expected!

Comment: You may also use `Request::createFrom(Request $request)` to create a new request:
`$newRequest = Request::createFrom($request);`

Comment: Oh, might try that soon